How to get Trello to respect the ratio of my covers on mobile?
I'm trying to make thin banner-like covers for my cards on a trello board.
If I use trello's default colour covers, it works well:
PC:

Android:

I'm trying to get the same effect, but with my own covers. On PC it works:

But on Android, my cover gets centred on a bigger canvas and takes too much space for no particular reason: 
Is there a way to fix this?

Please [edit] your question to explain in detail the steps you are taking to create the covers.  There isn't enough information to understand what steps you are taking and what you could/should change.

I am reviewing deleted closed questions.  I was the one who closed this so I'm adding it to the reopen-review queue to allow the community a chance to do its own review to decide if it should remain closed or be reopened. Notes: OP didn't respond to my comment, edit the question, or show any site activity following posting their question.
